# Multi conditions in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have `Thing` model which has an array of topics and followings.

I want to find all `things` that the `current_user` following its `Topic` or its 'User'.

```
@things = Thing
          .where(:user_id.in => current_user.following.map{ |u| u._id })
          .where(:topic_id.in => current_user.topics.map{ |u| u._id })
```

something like this. But this actually not working. it just returns records that common things between the both `where` conditions.

What I want is to return all the records that 2 `where` statements find.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.any_of(
  { :user_id.in => current_user.following.map{ |u| u._id } }, 
  { :topic_id.in => current_user.topics.map{ |u| u._id } }
)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I went for! Thank Jamal.

Comment: Though, thanks for Durran Jordan for answering it on twitter! https://twitter.com/modetojoy/status/86135667578503168

Answer (score 0):

it will be good to set the relations

```
references_one :user, :topic
```

and rely on smth
like

```
where :user.in => current_user.following, :topic.in =>current_user.topics...
```

Comment: I already implement the relations. But my code is now working the solution shown above